# DT (htmlwidgets content) for conflr

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

Any recommendations for rendering tables serverless with {rmarkdown}? I need to do this so I can push the rendered HTML to a Confluence page with the help of {conflr}.

When I render something like the below in an RMD file and then try to send to Confluence using `conflr:::confl_create_post_from_Rmd_addin()`, I get this error:

```
output file: serverless_test.knit.md

Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting commonmark-yaml_metadata_block output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: true

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
```

After adding the suggested flag, the table still does not render.

If I try to run it locally without pushing to Confluence using `DT:renderDT(..., server = FALSE)`, I get a warning `This R Markdown document contains Shiny content, but was rendered to a static file. Shiny content in the document may not appear, and will not be interactive.` In addition, the filter = "top" renders the text box at top of each column to filter column contents, but when you enter text nothing happens.

````
---
title: "serverless_dt"
author: "Matt Wood"
date: "2022-08-17"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
```

```{r}
DT::datatable(iris) 
# %>% DT::renderDT(server = FALSE)
```

conflr:::confl_create_post_from_Rmd_addin()
````

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For Rmd, you can just use `DT::datatable(iris)` without code after the pipe.

Comment: @lz100 Can you point to an example where the result does not require the server OR `Shiny` and allows for full interactivity of the datatable?

Comment: check the official website. The first example under Usage is the same as your question: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Comment: Updated OP to be more explicit as to what I'm trying to do. May be hard to test because it requires a Confluence subscription and a space in there which the user can edit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `DataTables(DT)` library is a `htmlwidgets` thing which isn't supported by `conflr`.

You can use only static content with the chunk option `screenshot.force = TRUE`

Comment: Thanks @manro, that does appear to be the problem. Do you have recommendations for a static table library that allows for background colorization in cells? I have a table with one column that needs red/yellow/green "stoplight" colors in the cells depending on their numeric value.

Comment: @M.Wood Maybe ```kableExtra```? https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html

Comment: Thanks, will try it. The table just above `Insert Images into Columns` section is close to what I would like to do.

Comment: @M.Wood Yes. If you will have new questions - you are welcome ;-)

Comment: Appears there is a bit of xml that `conflr` is choking on, even with kableExtra. Happens irrespective of `screenshot.force` setting.

````
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7525
Warning: Error in read_xml.raw: xmlParseEntityRef: no name [68]
  57: read_xml.raw
  56: read_xml.character
  54: translate_to_confl_macro
  53: confl_upload
  52: ::
shiny
observe
  51: <observer>
   8: shiny::runApp
   7: shiny::runGadget
   6: <Anonymous>
   4: output_format$post_processor
   3: rmarkdown::render
   2: confl_create_post_from_Rmd
   1: conflr:::confl_create_post_from_Rmd_addin

````

Comment: @M.Wood Hm, i don't know. Something again with ```conflr```. I wanted to experiment, but couldn't do it. We can't see the output in browser without access to Confluence?

Comment: yeah, from the error I think `conflr` is trying to convert the HTML to some Confluence XML schema to shove through Confluence API and burps when it gets to the table because the XML converter cannot handle that object.

Your earlier impulse to pass the table as an image was the right one I think. A more elegant/correct solution would be to use `httr2` or `rcurl` to pass a table using [Confluence's API](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Marketplace-Apps-Integrations/Create-a-table-in-Confluence-from-a-REST-API-call/ba-p/1393107).

FWIW, Confluence has a free tier. IDK about API support tho

Comment: @M.Wood Maybe, you shouldn't lose any sleep over this problem and simply save ```kableExtra``` table as image https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/save_kable_and_as_image.html and after paste it via ```knitr::include_graphics```?

Comment: I tried, but pulled the following error at the call to `kableExtra::as_image()`
`Error in include_graphics(temp_png, dpi = img_dpi) : 
Cannot find the file(s): "name_of_my_file.png"`

This may be a known issue with knitr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292022/knitr-cannot-find-img-files-in-static-folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247389/discussion-between-manro-and-m-wood).